# Rails - Working out how to access a method from a controller via a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a really basic question about rails - spent hours looking on the internet for a solution - but can not find a solution.

I just need to call a method on the clicking of a link.

The idea is I need to export an xml file that is generated by a method in the controller.

firms_controller.rb (exerpt)

```
.....def xml
    @entries = Entry.find(:all)
    send_data @entries.to_xml,
    :type => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8;',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=entries.xml"
end....
```

I just need to call this method from the firms view page to get the xml file to download, but cannot manage to get it to work. The XML code does work - if I add it to the index method in the controller it works flawlessly.

This is some of the ways I have attempted to get the link working after reading some online articles.

```
<% url = url_for({:action => "xml", :controller => 'firms'}.merge(params)) %>
<%= link_to "XML", url %>
```

The most basic way tried

```
<%= link_to "XML", :action => 'xml' %>
```

It seems to me like something that should be very simple - but cannot get it to work.

The error I am getting:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FirmsController#show

Couldn't find Firm with ID=xml

Rails.root: /home/james/rails/KPSmart
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/firms_controller.rb:25:in `show'
```

show method in firms_controller

```
  def show
  @firm = Firm.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Have tried messing with the routes to get it to work with no avail.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

In routes write this above your resource we written for firms controller

```
match 'firms/xml', :controller => 'firms', :action => 'xml',:as => :firms_xml
```

and link this in following way

```
<%= link_to "XML", firms_xml_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a routing issue or a link issue.  Do you need to pass the ID parameter to the XML controller method?  Your example links aren't showing that.  You need to look up how to pass parameters in your link_to helper:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

If you have the default routes setup in routes.rb:

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

Then your link_to should look like:

link_to "XML", :controller => "firms", :action => "xml", :id => 1234

where 1234 is the actual id you're trying to look up.

Comment: Tried your suggestion - but getting the same error (but the url is changing to: http://localhost:3000/firms/xml?id=1 instead). I do not need to pass the method any params - as I need it to return all of the "firms". Is there any easier way to do this, would what you recommend for the routes?

Answer (score 1):

Check that link URL!

I don't think it's what you're expecting.  When you merge two hashes via `hash1.merge(hash2)`, any duplicate keys will yield those from `hash2`.  And since (if I recall correctly) the `params` hash has `:action` and `:controller` keys added to it during Rails's routing process, you're having your expected route overridden by the route to the current (show) page.

You could try `reverse_merge`, which would give you a more predictable result, but I'd recommend using Rails's path generation helpers to make your life even easier:

```
<%= link_to "XML", firm_xml_path(@firm) %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey - tried link_to "XML", xml_firms_path(@firm)
But it throwing the following error again with different params:  Couldn't find Firm with ID=xml
<{"format"=>["1",
 "2",
 "3",
 "4",
 "5",
 "6",
 "7",
 "8",
 "9",
 "10"],
 "id"=>"xml"}

.... I do not want the page to refresh, I just want it to evaluate the function in the controller, which will download an xml file